# file saved outside from eclipse is compiled automatically?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a spring mvc web project configured in eclipse. Web application is running via tomcat server built inside eclipse. I have seen as soon as I change something and save the code, the project is rebuild and new web application is available for browsing. All this build-deploy is done behind the scenes.

If I have my project running on a server through eclipse and I changed one of project files from some an external tool like notepad++ and save it from there, will my new changes be build-deploy automatically in eclipse?

If not how can I achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Window / Preferences / General / Workspace then check

Refresh using native hooks or polling
Refresh on access

Answer (score 2):

I guess if you will refresh project in eclipse after changed some file from notepad it will automatically be deployed.

Comment: is there any plugin or setting that can refresh eclipse automatically as soon a file changed from outside?

Answer (score 1):

Refresh the Project inside which file is changed and the project would/should be built automatically and published